# JSON array to nodejs Readable object stream

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream

I have an event that fires every time a packet is received from a bluetooth device. The packet comes in as a JSON array and always contains 10 objects similar to the ones below.

```
var s1_data = [{"record":0,"sensor":1,"timestamp":26566,"date":{"day":7,"hour":10,"minute":45,"month":5,"second":38,"year":18}},
{"record":1,"sensor":1,"timestamp":26567,"date":{"day":7,"hour":10,"minute":45,"month":5,"second":38,"year":18}},
{"record":2,"sensor":1,"timestamp":26568,"date":{"day":7,"hour":10,"minute":45,"month":5,"second":38,"year":18}},
{"record":3,"sensor":1,"timestamp":26569,"date":{"day":7,"hour":10,"minute":45,"month":5,"second":38,"year":18}},
{"record":4,"sensor":1,"timestamp":26570,"date":{"day":7,"hour":10,"minute":45,"month":5,"second":38,"year":18}},
{"record":5,"sensor":1,"timestamp":26571,"date":{"day":7,"hour":10,"minute":45,"month":5,"second":38,"year":18}},
{"record":6,"sensor":1,"timestamp":26572,"date":{"day":7,"hour":10,"minute":45,"month":5,"second":38,"year":18}},
{"record":7,"sensor":1,"timestamp":26573,"date":{"day":7,"hour":10,"minute":45,"month":5,"second":38,"year":18}},
{"record":8,"sensor":1,"timestamp":26574,"date":{"day":7,"hour":10,"minute":45,"month":5,"second":38,"year":18}},
{"record":9,"sensor":1,"timestamp":26575,"date":{"day":7,"hour":10,"minute":45,"month":5,"second":38,"year":18}}]
```

I need to push each individual object into a node.js stream that is being consumed by another stream.

Can anyone give an example on how I can push these to a Readable object stream on an ongoing basis (or do I need to use a PassThrough stream)? I can’t seem to get my head around how to do this!

**Edited to add sample code below. chunk.toString() fails as chunk is undefined**

```
var Readable = require('stream').Readable;
var util = require('util');
var through2 = require('through2');

var s1 = require('./sensor1.js');
var s2 = require('./sensor2.js');

var minLength = s1.length;
//console.log(s1);
var s1stream = new Readable({ objectMode: true });
var s2stream = new Readable({ objectMode: true });


s1stream._read = function () {
    this.push();
};

s2stream._read = function () {
    this.push();
};

if (s2.length < minLength){
  minLength = s2.length;
}

var n1 = 0;
setInterval(function() {
    if (n1++ < minLength) {
        console.log(s1[n1].record);
        s1stream.push(s1[n1]);
    } else if (n1++ === minLength) {
        s1stream.push(null);
    }
}, 1000);

var n2 = 0;
setInterval(function() {
    if (n2++ < minLength) {
        s2stream.push(s2[n2]);
    } else if (n2++ === minLength) {
        s2stream.push(null);
    }
}, 1000);


s1stream.pipe(through2.obj(function (chunk, enc, callback) {
    this.push(chunk.toString())
    callback()
  })).pipe(process.stdout);
```

**Edit below shows working code. Looks like it was to do with the way I was creating the** `read` **functions**

```
var Readable = require('stream').Readable;
var util = require('util');
var through2 = require('through2');
var Transform = require('stream').Transform;

var s1 = require('./sensor1.js');
var s2 = require('./sensor2.js');

var minLength = s1.length;
//console.log(s1);

var s1stream = new Readable({
   objectMode: true,
   read() {}
 })

 const s2stream = new Readable({
    objectMode: true,
    read() {}
  })

if (s2.length < minLength){
  minLength = s2.length;
}

var n1 = 0;
setInterval(function() {
    if (n1 < minLength) {
        s1stream.push(s1[n1]);
        n1++;
    } else if (n1 == minLength) {
        s1stream.push(null);
    }
}, 1000);

var n2 = 0;
setInterval(function() {
    if (n2++ < minLength) {
        s2stream.push(s2[n2]);
    } else if (n2++ === minLength) {
        s2stream.push(null);
    }
}, 1000);

var jsonStream = through2.obj(function(file, encoding, cb) {
    this.push(file.record.toString())
    cb()
})

s1stream.pipe(jsonStream).pipe(process.stdout);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to implement a Readable stream that "wraps" your bluetooth source. When the packet received event is fired you'll loop through your array of objects and call your Readable stream's `push` method, passing in each object. A somewhat similar example of this can be seen [here](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_push_chunk_encoding)

Note that since you'll be sending actual JSON objects you'll want to enable the objectMode option when you write your implementation as described [here](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_new_stream_readable_options)

Comment: Many thanks. I've added some sample code to the question. For some reason when I try to pipe the objects back to stdout via through2 I'm getting an error saying that `chunk.toString()` is undefined. This code works fine when not in object mode (and without the through2 pipe). Can you spot where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Got it sorted. Was related to the way I was creating the `read`  functions for the two `Readable` streams. Have added working code to my question.